# dropping table using presto doesn't drop tables from warehouse

Tags: hdfs, presto

I am trying to drop a table using presto, actually metadata gets dropped but table data in /user/hive/warehouse still exists.

Upon further digging I found that this behavior was possibly due to the sticky bit which was getting applied to the database and all the tables inside the database.

drwxrwxrw**t**   - hadoop hadoop          0 2017-11-29 13:40 /user/hive/warehouse/testmanishdb.db

now if I try to remove the sticky bit applied on the database using the below command

```
hadoop fs -chmod -t  /user/hive/warehouse/testmanishdb.db/
```

sticky bit gets removed as can be seen below

drwxrwxrwx   - hadoop hadoop          0 2017-11-29 13:44 /user/hive/warehouse/testmanishdb.db

Now going forward if I create a table in presto and drop the table its metadata and corresponding /user/hive/warehouse/ data on the HDFS also gets deleted.

Though this behavior is only observed in presto, even without removing sticky bit if I drop table using hive/spark both metadata and data gets deleted.

Thanks
Manish